# Can malware spread between parititions on a hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, malware

Let's say I have a computer that dual-boots from two partitions on the same hard drive. If I get infected with malware while using one of the partitions, how likely is it that it will spread to the other partition if it is running a different operating system?

What if it is running the same operating system?

What if I was using two separate hard drives connected to the same computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could spread fairly easily if the same [file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system) is used on both partitions. E.g., if you boot into Microsoft Windows from a partition formatted with the [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) file system and the other partition also is formatted with NTFS and is visible to the operating system then the malware can "see" the other partition and its files. If, however, the other partition uses the [ext3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3), [XFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS), or some other file system commonly used on Linux systems or some other operating system that the operating system from which you booted the system doesn't recognize, then it would not be impossible, but would be much more difficult for the malware to spread, since, unless you've added support for the other file system to Windows yourself, the malware would have to include code within itself to be able to mount other file systems.

It doesn't matter much if the second partition is internally attached or externally attached, e.g., through a USB connection, in how easy it is for the malware to spread. If the malware author has chosen to attempt to put the malware into files on any available drives, and some do, and the operating system you've booted into has that other partition mounted and recognizes its filesystem, then the malware author won't have much trouble, in spreading the malware, especially if the malware doesn't rely upon modifications to the registry or system files, but looks for .exe, .doc, .xls, .pdf or some other commonly found file type to infect.

External drives, such as USB flash drives, SD Cards etc. may be more attractive to a malware author as targets than infecting another partition on an internal drive that will likely remain in a system he has already infected. Since they are likely to be moved from system to system, infecting them allows the malware author to more easily spread his malware. [Stuxnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet#Windows_infection) used such a technique.